# How to get active device list from Google Cloud IoT core

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, iot

I'm using Google's cloud-iot-core in my project with Firebase/Firestore. I've devices in my iot core registry, I want to get active devices from iot core using command or using iot core liabrary(Java/Python). I want to show/update active device in android app and also on Firebase/Firestore. How can I do that??

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud IoT exposes a REST interface that can be used to interrogate the state of devices.  Specifically, there is an API called `projects.locations.registries.devices.list` which can be used to return a list of all devices.

https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/reference/cloudiot/rest/v1/projects.locations.registries.devices/list

Using this API, you get back a list of Device objects:

https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/reference/cloudiot/rest/v1/projects.locations.registries.devices#Device

which contains the identity of each device as well as fields such as `lastHeartbeatTime`.  In your original question, you didn't define what you meant by *active* as it relates to a device so I am assuming that would be either `lastHeartbeatTime` or `lastEventTime`.

Comment: I'm using MQTT to connect to cloud iot core, I want devices which are currently connected/active or Live.

Comment: The issue with this approach is that those fields are empty in the response that I am getting.